# Loopback push array

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How would I go about making a custom `remoteMethod` that updates/pushes, *not overrides*, a property that is an `array`. 
So basically `push` data to an array property of a model.

I can't find any clear examples of this in the documentation, except for an `.add()` helper method, but that requires an `embedsOne` or some other relation.

But what if I have a *single* `Model` in my whole app and would just want to `push` some data to an `id`. 
So ending up with an endpoint like:

`POST /Thing/{id}/pushData`

And the body to `POST` would be:

```
  {
     id: "foo",
     data: "bar"
   }
```

(Or preferably without `id`, and have the `id` `autoInserted`, since it's an array, and I don't need an id for each item, the `data` part should be searchable with filters/where)

So far I have:

```
  Thing.remoteMethod (
      'pushData',
      {
        isStatic: false,
        http: {path: '/pushData', verb: 'post'},
        accepts: [
          { arg: 'data', type: 'array', http: { source: 'body' } }
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'put', type: 'string'},
        description: 'push some Data'
      }
  );

  Thing.prototype.pushData = function(data, cb) { 
    data.forEach(function (result) {
      // ??
    });
    cb(null, data)
  };
```

And as far as I can see, the default endpoints only allow single instances to be added, but I want to update in bulk.

Comment: By "updates/pushes", do you mean you want to use the array as a queue and use the rest api to put and pop data from it ? Something like that right ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: @Overdrivr, thing is, I don't want' to have to overwrite the whole array, because that would probably be very slow when it comes to thousands of requests. I'd like to use some native loopback functionality like `.add()`, although I have no idea how loopback does this internally, but I'm assuming it's more efficient than, overwriting a thousand-length array...

Comment: Have you benchmarked it ? You need to make sure you really have a problem regarding performances otherwise you will spend time trying to fix things that aren't broken in the first place.

Comment: However, if I understand correctly, you want to add a thousand items to your array in one request rather than making a thousand request that add 1 item. Is this correct ?

Comment: @Overdrivr, yes exactly

Comment: Any updates on this question ? Could you please provide feedback for others ?

Answer (score 1):

You have made your method non-static, which is good.

Now, if your array property is called `MyArray`, I would try something along the lines of :

```
  Thing.remoteMethod (
      'pushData',
      {
        isStatic: false,
        http: {path: '/pushData', verb: 'post'},
        accepts: [
          { arg: 'data', type: 'array', http: { source: 'body' } }
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'put', type: 'string'},
        description: 'push some Data'
      }
  );

  Thing.prototype.pushData = function(data, cb) {
    thingInstance = this; 
    data.forEach(function (result) {
       thingInstance.MyArray.push(result.data);
    });

    cb(null, data)
  };
```

Since your remote method is non-static, you should able to access the instance using `this`. I have a doubt whether or not you can directly access properties that way by writing `this.someProperty`, please try it and let me know if that doesn't work.

Then to create in bulk just make a standard POST request to your remote

```
POST /Thing/{id}/pushData
```

just write your JSON like this

```
{
   {
       data: "bar"
   },
   {
       data: "foo"
   },
   //etc
}
```

This should add two elements to the array property.

Let me know if this is helpful