# Loopback push string to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

My question is similar to [this question asked in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223393/loopback-push-array) which unfortunately does not have an accepted answer. I'm also unable to use the answer there to figure out how I need to accomplish the same.

I am basically trying to add a new item to an array in my data model.

My current data model (What I want) is like this:

```
{
   teamId: 'team32',
   teamName: 'Lions',
   players: ['Jack','Ryan','Sam']
}
```

When a new team is created, an empty array is added for 'players'. There is no model for players. It is just an array which can hold a list of players.

How do I add a new player to the list of players (Add a string to the list)? I'm also open to storing it as an object instead of string.

My Team model

```
{
  "name": "teams",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "teamID": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "teamName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "players":{
      "type":"array",
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

team.js

```
var updateQuery = {players:{$addToSet:{'Mark'}}};

team.update({teamID:'teams32'},updateQuery,
     function(err,data){
         console.log(err,data,'result');
      });
```

$addToSet and $push have both worked for me with MongoDB with mongoose. But somehow don't seem to work on loopback. How do I go about this since $addToSet and $push are both not working for me in this case?

Comment: Try this `team.update(
 { "teamID": "teams32" },
 { "$addToSet": { "properties.players": "Mark" }},
)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I tried this out. But same result. {"$addToSet":{"properties.players":"Mark"}} objects gets added to the players field, instead of adding to the list. I am also confused at how the datatype switches from array to object after this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deserves two calls but might help you:

```
team.addPlayer = function (player, cb) {
    team.findOne({where: {teamID: "teams32"}}, function (err, team) {
        if (!err && team) {
            var players = [];
            if (team.players) {
                players = team.players;
            }
            players.push(player);
            team.updateAttributes({players: players}, function(err, team) {
                cb (err, team);
            });
        } else {
            cb (err, {});
        }
    });
};

team.remoteMethod('addPlayer', {
    accepts: {arg: 'player', type: 'string', required: true},
    returns: {arg: 'team', type: 'object'},
    http: {verb: 'put'}
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I decided to go with this approach since I could not find any other way. But this involves querying the database twice. I would prefer to do it with a single query to reduce the amount of work done on the application level and also to reduce the number of queries. Is this not possible with loopback?

Comment: I agree, but I'm not seeing anything else. Have you tried what @ Anthony Winzlet has suggested in his comment?

Comment: Yup I tried that as well. But didnt work for me. It is rather amusing because I have used both $push and $addToSet successfully with Mongoose on ExpressJS. But it simply doesnt work with Loopback.

Comment: is there any better solution than this approach ?

Comment: I stopped developping on LoopbackJs - but did you try @Ricardo Pinto 's answer?

Answer (score 3):

You should extend your model capabilities to use those operators.
Something like:

```
"options": {    
    "mongodb": {
      "collection": "model_collection",
      "allowExtendedOperators": true
    }
  },
```

As stated in loopback documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/MongoDB-connector.html

Then you can just use it like:

```
team.update({teamID:'teams32'},{ $addToSet:{ players: 'Mark'}},
     function(err,data){
         console.log(err,data,'result');
      });
```

Comment: im guessing loopback has no support for addToSet on the client side via the SDK

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge the find, update and any other functions here in loopback is not same as MongoDB native query. It has their own customizations. So
**team.update** is not same as **db.team.update()**.
So, Either you can use 2 db queries as said in the previous answer or you can try by running native query by getting the **datasource**. Then you can use **$addToSet**  easily and it will do the job in a single hit.

```
team.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection("team");
    collection.update(filter,{$addToSet: {players:{$addToSet:{'Mark'}}}}, function(err,res){ /*Anything you want to do here*/ })
})
```

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented this endpoint with node --version v10.16.0 and loopback@3.26.0

With it I can append values to any field in my model (only handling array type field currently). the data param should look like `[ "one", 2, true ]`

```
    Dataset.appendToArrayField = function (id, fieldName, data, ctx, next) {
    const where = {pid: id};
    var $addToSet = {};
    // $each is necessary as data is an array of values
    // $addToSetis necessary to append to the field and not overwrite
    $addToSet[fieldName] = { $each: data };
    Dataset.update(where,  { $addToSet });
    next();
};

Dataset.remoteMethod("appendToArrayField", {
    accepts: [{
            arg: "id",
            type: "string",
            required: true,
            description: ""
        },
        {
            arg: "fieldName",
            type: "string",
            required: true,
            description: "Name of field to append data to"
        },
        {
            arg: "data",
            type: "array",
            required: true,
            description: "An array of values to append"
        },
        {
            arg: 'options',
            type: 'object',
            http: {
                source: 'context'
            }
        }
    ],
    http: {
        path: "/appendToArrayField",
        verb: "post"
    },
    returns: {
        type: "Object",
        root: true
    },
    description: "updates a single record by appending data to the specified field"
});
```